# X minutes from now in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

i tried making a program that executes X minutes after the user gets to that point in the code. i thought of making a variable for the minutes and making another variable wich is that +X. and than a while loop. but if you have 10 minutes for example and the current time is 12:53 that is not going to work as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider `time.sleep()`:

```
print ('now')
time.sleep(10 * 60)  # Ten minutes
print ('later')
```